# converting formula into string vba

Tags: excel, vba

My excel file has 3 different type of VBA functions. In a sheet, I want to show the value from the defined name function. Initially I used this code to convert formula into string:

```
Function EvaluateString(strTextString As String)
    Application.Volatile
    EvaluateString = Evaluate(strTextString)
End Function
```

This function was placed in a individual module. The problem with this is that it runs in every module causing the running time for my other modules to be extremely slow.

I tried placing this function in a module itself, but it does not work. It gave me an error of "Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function, or End Property".

This is my code when I received that prompt

```
Sub PasteAsText()

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Worksheets("Data_Column").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Function EvaluateString(strTextString As String)
    Application.Volatile
    EvaluateString = Evaluate(strTextString)
End Function

Worksheets("Data_Column").Range("D1:D" & lastRow).Clear

Worksheets("Data_Column").Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Copy
Worksheets("Data_Column").Range("D1:D" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Worksheets("Data_Column").Range("D1:D" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "@"
Worksheets("Data_Column").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Where exactly are you using `EvaluateString`? I would only expect it to slow things down if it was being used in thousands of cells. Also, why have you tried placing it within the code of a sub? That doesn't make sense, and as you found out won't allow the code to compile.

Comment: im using EvaluateString on sheet "Data_Column". i use =EvaluateString(A1) to find the value of the defined name

Comment: You've put the Function() inside an existing Sub() definition.  No can do

Comment: I tried placing the function in its own module but it cause my other codes to run very slowly. Is there anyway i can improve on it?

Comment: What's the purpose of the function?

Comment: it helps me to get the defined name value. A little more context, on Data_Column sheet, column A is all the defined names, column b is the list of all the formulas that garner the defined name values, column c is where "=EvaluateString(A1)" was used

Comment: In the code you have shown you put the `EvaluateString` function INSIDE the `PasteAsText` subroutine.  That's why it is complaining about text after the `End Function`  Move the `EvaluateString` function BELOW the `PasteAsText` subroutine and it won't have that error.

Comment: i did you said. I have over 2000+ data, while using the Function, it makes my program run slowly. Do u know how to improve from it?

Comment: i place my function at paste as text module however, my other modules will run the function despite it not being on the same module. How can i prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to see a formula as a text, you can use the `FormulaText()` function, as explained in [this URL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/formulatext-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8).

So instead of your function `PasteText()` you can simply do something like:

```
Destination = FormulaText(Source)                                           // simple Excel OR
Destination.Value = Application.WorkSheetFunction.FormulaText(Source.Value) // VBA
```